# Network inside Windows 10 vm (Hyper-V) really slow

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I just upgraded my Windows 10 home edition to an enterprise version and installed Hyper-V and created a Windows 10 image.

I haven't changed and settings on the image or Hyper-V everything is stock.

But the network inside the Win10 vm is very slow. Downloading a file thats 350mb takes 8 hours. I'm getting 14kb/s, whereas on my machine I'm getting 15mb/s.

Why is the network so slow inside my Hyper-V VM?

Comment: Which network configuration do you use in Hyper-V? Did you try  uninstalling and reinstalling Hyper-V network switch work?

Comment: I use the default, nope I did not uninstall/install anything.

Comment: I mean which network external, internal or private?

Answer (score 0):

It's been hours, but I've finally found a solution to my same issue. I saw several that said to disable bandwidth management, but by default it's off. I finally enabled it, and set it to about half my bandwidth, 25mbps in this case, and 50 for the max, and suddenly it's literally a thousand times faster (just 1mbps, but I'll take it, i haven't tried setting it higher but it might help too). Whew. Hope that helps you.